# ¿Como puedo abrir el mismo reportes en el mismo formulario?

Tags: c#

Tengo mi siguiente formulario:
que se llama frmNot
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Posteriormente al dar clic sobre el botón de la lupa me manda a otro formulario que es un catalogo de datos (frmCat) el cual al dar clic sobre alguno de ellos me genera el reporte.
La cuestión es que me abre un formulario, lo cual yo no quiero, quiero que al dar clic sobre la fila me abra el reporte sobre el mismo formulario frmNot, mas no quiero que me habrá otro. tengo mi siguiente código dentro del formulario frmCat.

```
 private void btnSeleccionar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        frmNot log = new frmNot();
        log.NumRef = dgvResultados.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        String NO_REFEREN = dgvResultados.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();

        log.Show();

       log.txt1.Text = NO_REFEREN;

    }
```

y de igual forma intente con la siguiente opción de código:

```
  private void dgvResultados_CellDoubleClick_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

              frmNot log = Owner as frmNot;
              log.NumRef = dgvResultados.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();

             String NumRef = dgvResultados.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();


              String NO_REFEREN = dgvResultados.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();

              log.Show();

             log.txt1.Text = NO_REFEREN;

             log.reportViewer1.Text = NumRef;




    }
```

y en mi frmNot tengo mi siguiente codigo:

```
 private void buscarfol_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        frmCat log = new frmCat();
        AddOwnedForm(log);
        log.ShowDialog();


    }
```

Espero me puedan ayudar gracias.

Comment: @sstan No ya eh hecho eso antes en este caso es diferente.

Comment: Aunque no es idéntico, me parece que la misma técnica aplicaría muy bien en este situación.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo tenia que invocar mi metodo, utilizar el Owner y el as

```
    private void btnSeleccionar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    frmNot log = Owner as frmNot();
    log.NumRef = dgvResultados.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    String NO_REFEREN = dgvResultados.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    log.cargarReporte();


    log.Show();


   log.txt1.Text = NO_REFEREN;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

lo que podrías hacer es colocar el código que carga el reporte como un procedimiento en el código del formulario frmNot. De esta forma:

```
public void cargarReporte(String valor){

          NumRef = valor;


          String NO_REFEREN = valor;

         .txt1.Text = NO_REFEREN;

         reportViewer1.Text = NumRef
```

}

Luego, llamas al procedimiento en el formulario frmCat.

```
 private void dgvResultados_CellDoubleClick_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
frmNot.cargarReporte(dgvResultados.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
}
```